# How to Debug TouchScreen Events?

Tags: javascript, html, touchscreen

I have a Windows 10 PC **without** touchscreen. I have an Android phone **with** touchscreen.

I have put my test touchscreen code on my website to test and have tried it on my phone. It does not work.

So I looked for MoreTools|DeveloperTools in Google Chrome on my phone, but it does not exist.

How do I debug or see the errors?

Is there any way I can get the errors from my phone appearing on my PC?

Is there any way to get MoreTools|DeveloperTools on my phone's Google Chrome?

Are there any emulators around the www I can use on my PC so I can emulate touchscreen?

Comment: There's a handy how to guide here that shows you how to link desktop chrome dev tools to remote android device: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is an USB cable and a Chrome browser. You can access devtools by going to chrome://inspect.

https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/google-chrome-how-to-inspect-websites-on-mobile-devices-804677f863ce